# Unable to login to WSO AppFactory

Tags: wso2

WSO2 experts

I downloaded the WSO2 AppFactory, but couldn't login into the web console with admin/admin. Has the default password changed?

Regards,
Terry

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the following credentials

```
Username:admin@admin.com
password:admin
```

Comment: Thanks! admin@admin.com works. Why it's not admin anymore? And where can I find the documents and guide? I couldn't find the documents on wso2.com.

Comment: @admin.com refers to the tenant where as admin is the username

Comment: I found this on \wso2appfactory-1.0.0\repository\conf\usr-mgt.xml file. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you just tried with a downloaded 'binary' set-up of WSO2 App Factory; this will only allow you to log in to the **Carbon admin console** of the App Factory (If you just clicked on and visited the URL, that was printed on the server console). This **Carbon admin console** does not have any App Factory specific functionality which you might expect [WSO2 Carbon is the underlying platform which is used by all of the WSO2 products].

Since App Factory runs having few other servers alongside (such as WSO2 AS, WSO2 ELB, Jenkins, Redmine etc) this set up that you are running will ***not*** provide the same User interfaces or functionality which you have observed within the setup provided with https://appfactorypreview.wso2.com/samlsso .

I just thought to leave this answer, because; you would get disappointed after spending your time expecting the same Application (User Interfaces) available with the online setup (which I have mentioned with the hyperlink) by running the binary setup(wso2appfactory-1.0.0.zip) that you have downloaded from the WSO2 Web site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Kulasinghe! It's good to know that many other servers are needed to have something like appfactorypreview.wso2.com. Actually we are trying to setup the AppFactory becasuse we aim to provide PAAS for our customers, so we would need the functionalities like AppServer in the future. It would be nice if we could have a comprehensive document for setting it up on our own machines.

Comment: Since there are several servers, puppet script would be released to automate the setup the near future.