# How to run appfacotry in local machine?

Tags: wso2

I have downloaded WSO2 appfacotry and ran it locally for testing purposes. It first gives carbon login and in the running application list I could see the /appmgt jaggery application is running. Then I tried to go to the url through the link provided in Action column in that application list. Initially I was routed to http://{some_ip_address}:9763/appmgt/ and then I was re routed to https://appfactory.example.com:9443/samlsso which gives me error. (because I don't have appfacotry.example.com domain.) How can I run appfactory without this faulty URL?

Comment: See the answer given to [1].

[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805634/unable-to-login-to-wso-appfactory

Comment: @Lahiru Thanks for the quick response. I went through that answer. We are doing a test installation so would like to see what are the servers needed to be run. Is there any documentations to do that? We just wanted to see the process.

Comment: Servers would be Jenkins, LDAP, Redmine, GitBlits, and database servers in addition to WSO2 servers. As i also mentioned at the other place, documents will be provided along with puppet script in the near future. Because configuring those with App-factory manually is a cumbersome way.

Comment: Thanks @Lahiru for the information. Waiting to see the complete puppet scripts.

Comment: @Lahiru what are the necessary WSO2 servers needed to be running in order to get all features of appfacotry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's documentation on installing App Factory: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AF201/Installing+On-Premise

Also, note that there is now a hosted version, which you can use in the cloud with no configuration required: http://wso2.com/cloud/app-cloud/

Answer (score 1):

Other than the 3rd party tools mentioned above, you need App Factory, AS, API manager, Stratos Controller and ELB to have all App Factory features